# Django Form inheritance on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I need inherit one form based on another as described in [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance). I have created next code:

```
'''models'''

class Blog(db.Model):
    slug = db.StringProperty('blog url', required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty('blog name', required=True)
    author = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True, required=True)

'''forms'''

class BlogCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author',)

    def clean_slug(self):
        return "something"

class BlogEditForm(BlogCreateForm):
    class Meta(BlogCreateForm.Meta):
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author', 'slug')
```

I print this forms and see similar results - shown two fields - name and slug. But expected one field "name" in result of rendering BlogEditForm.

**NOTE** that I run this code on **Google App Engine** with **Django 1.2.1**.

Now I have used form without inheritance and this work well:

```
class BlogEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author', 'slug')
```

**I think that current situation based on Google App Engine implementation of forms patcher.**

Comment: Read more about djangoforms patcher in Google App Engine - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/djangoforms.py.

Comment: Who have an ideas about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to split out the `clean_slug` method out of the `BlogCreateForm` class, since that's the only thing that's really being reused. Doing something such as the following should get what you want.

```
class CleanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_slug(self):
        return "something"

class BlogCreateForm(CleanForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author',)

class BlogEditForm(CleanForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author', 'slug')
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have found this solution yet. Thank you. This works!